# How to find IP address of desktop pc which is connected to android device through USB

Tags: java, android, ip-address

I would like to find IP address of desktop pc which is connected to android device through USB. In each thread on stack overflow and any other website I found that returns device's IP address. But I want to desktop PC's IP address which is connected to android device.

Is there any Android API available for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't this is possible, in general.

- If the phone is connected as a mass storage device, I'm pretty sure (without looking at the spec) that the USB mass storage device class does not include this information. Why would it? It makes no sense.
- The very idea of "the IP address" is a bit off; a computer can have *any number* of IP addresses, not just one. Think of computers with several network cards.

You might be able to implement something using a custom connection type, if possible on your phone, but then it would likely need PC-side support too.

Answer (score 0):

Your friend for this is `arp`. Specifically, you can read the file `/proc/net/arp` which will have the format

```
IP address       HW type     Flags       HW address            Mask     Device
192.168.1.249    0x1         0x2         00:08:9b:bf:a9:fc     *        eth0
192.168.1.252    0x1         0x2         00:0d:a2:01:15:ed     *        eth0
192.168.1.172    0x1         0x0         00:00:00:00:00:00     *        eth0
```

Cheers,

Comment: Im surprised google doesn't have this - for windows mobile development there is standard NAT'd address that is effectily "locahost" on the PC the device is attached to.  It is extremely useful to test device clients with server code and run both in the debuggers at the same time.